# By Default load some data into our database sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to insert some tables by default to our `sqllite` db.

I want to display different items according to different categories. In the application, a user can also add items and new categories, for that purpose I want to add some data to db by default. How can we add data to `sqlite` by default. Please give me some suggestions.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pre-package the database by creating the database with a [SQLite database editor](http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=ManagementTools) and then put the pre-made database in your assets folder which you can then access from your app.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you use the `SQLiteOpenHelper`, as in the Notepad tutorial.

`SQLiteOpenHelper`'s `onCreate()` method is called if the database is not yet created. This is the place where initial population of the tables should happen.